# Copy identical fields of different struct in rust

Tags: rust

Let's suppose we have two structs with identical fields (and types).

```
struct A {
  pub data1: i32;
  pub data2: string;
}

struct B {
  pub data1: i32;
  pub data2: string;
}
```

To copy the struct A and B, I have to do

```
fn convert_A_to_B(a: A) -> B {
  B {
    data1: a.data1,
    data2: a.data2
  }
}
```

I wish I can do something like

```
B {
  ..a
}
```

but it's not possible since types are different. Is there any macro or syntax that do the simple move of all identical fields?

Comment: @Jmb, it is a duplicate indeed. But I am not sure the other answer actually covers it well. What is the action to follow here? Close this one and answer in the other?

Comment: I checked the other solutions but they all revolves around using serde to serialize and deserialize? But wouldn't they incur unnecessary overhead for serlization?

Comment: @Jaebum The solution using `to_value()` and `from_value()` introduces relatively little overhead, and is generally what I would go with at the moment. Even Rust structs with identical defintions are allowed to have different memory layouts, unless you specify `#[repr(C)]`, as in the answer below, so simply transmuting doesn't work in general. If you want to avoid the small overhead of `to_value()` and `from_value()`, you probably need to write the boilerplate code for that (or roll your own macro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure of the **struct memory layout is the same** you can use `std::mem::transmute`:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
  pub data1: i32,
  pub data2: String
}

#[repr(C)]
struct B {
  pub data1: i32,
  pub data2: String
}

impl From<B> for A {
    fn from(b: B) -> A {
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(b) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b = B {data1: 10, data2: "Foo".to_string()};
    let a: A = b.into();
    
    println!("{a:?}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2fdf36bb968f890387f1c56a094c9653)

Comment: This seems very unsafe, will cause all kinds of issues if the memory layout is subtly different. Should probably include a disclaimer.

Comment: @mausetail....there is a disclaimer, it is literally the first sentence in the answer.

Comment: The `repr(C)` attributes actually guarantee that the memory layout only depends on order and type of the fields, so if both structs have fields with the same types in the same order, this is safe.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, yes, that is why I added it. Not sure if there is any other `repr` that would work, since it is not a feature I daily use.